# Electron - Selectors :first-child and :nth-child

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, electron

It seems like Electron won't allow selectors such as `:first-child` and `:nth-child`.
For example, for the following HTML:

```
<div class="tabs" id="first">Block 1</div>
<div class="tabs" id="second">Block 2</div>
<div class="tabs" id="third">Block 3</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.tabs:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Electron would just not execute the CSS, therefore the first `<div>` would still appear.

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: what is the chrome version ?

Comment: Looks a bit odd, I don't think such selectors are prohibited. Worst case scenario use `.tabs#first` or an additional class to your elements

Comment: @FastSnail 58.0.3029.110, according to the `navigator.userAgent`.

Comment: @Fotis Is there any solution but using `.tabs#first`? I'd even install a node package via npm to use this functionality, if there was one.

Comment: @avi12 electron chrome version ?did you check from electron >  toggle developer tools ?

Comment: Yeah. I already marked your answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap your divs inside a parent like this

```
 <div>
            <div class="tabs" id="first">Block 1</div>
            <div class="tabs" id="second">Block 2</div>
            <div class="tabs" id="third">Block 3</div>
 </div>
```

now first-child will work.tested and working
i think reason is now first one is first child of it's parent